# Disable ajax for an imagebutton control inside a GridTemplateColumn of an ajaxified RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

In an ajaxified RadGrid I want two buttons to cause a postback (bypass Ajax) and execute some back-end code. Here's what I have so far...

Buttons (just showing one for simplicity):

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Actions">  
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEdit" runat="server" OnClientClick="realPostBack();"  ImageUrl="~/images/icon_edit.png" style="display: inline-block" ToolTip="Edit" CommandName="fbEdit"  />
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Javascript function I'm using to disable the postback:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function realPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    $find("<%= RadAjaxPanel1.ClientID %>").__doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument);
  }
```

Code-behind I want to execute:

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.CommandName == "fbEdit")
  {
    //grab variables from row's cells
   string userID = e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["UserID"];
   string userName= e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["UserName"];
   string userEmail = e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["UserEmail"];

   //DO SOME PROCESSING STUFF

  }
   if(e.CommandName == "fbDelete")
    {
       //delete record
     }
  }
```

So the post back does indeed occur, but my code never fires. I'm guessing it's because the event is tied to the grid and not to buttons im "un-ajaxifying", but I went this way because I NEED to capture the values of some of the cells in the row that the button was clicked.

Maybe I can rework this to use the buttons onClick Event, but I would still need to capture those values.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the look of things you are attempting to execute code in the OnItemCommand event of the RadGrid, but it seems like you might be making things a bit over-complicated. Why not use a **GridButtonColumn**, set the **ButtonType** to *ImageButton* and then set the same **CommandName** as you do above? As long as you're subscribing to the OnItemCommand event this should trigger everything to get called and your conditional check for `e.CommandName == "fbEdit"` should be hit as well.

For an example of how to use this RadGrid specific column (in a similar manner) you can check out [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/columntypes/defaultcs.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

In you need to add bellow code in PageLoad Event.

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
 {
     RadGridName.Rebind();
 }
```

thats it.